# How to show keyboard not in floating mode

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

I have devices onepluse that have strange keyboard behavior. When I use

> android:imeOptions="actionDone|flagNoFullscreen"

for edittext it opens keyboard in floating mode.

Any option to control floating mode of keyboard?
[image]